# What's happening inside this method?

Tags: java, recursion

I can't quite figure out what's happening inside this method when I call it with 2 as argument.

```
public int foo(int i) { 
    if (i > 0) { 
        System.out.println(”i: ” + foo(i - 1)); 
    } 
    return i; 
}
```

This method returns two i.

1) i:0

2) i:1

I tried to understand this way. When the method is called with foo(2), the value of **i** is **2** and that is greater than zero. So it passes the if test. And then the method recalls itself in the print method; foo(2-1) which is foo(1). And now the value of **i** is **1** which again passes the if test; and in the print method foo(1-1) becomes foo(0) which does not pass the if test, so it returns the value of **i** which is zero now. What I don't understand here is where the second value of **i** which is **1** come from.

I ask for your help. Thank you.

Comment: Draw the trace and you'll understand.

Comment: This is a recursive function - search for that term. But to understand recursion you must first understand recursion

Comment: **To understand what a recrusion is, you need to understand what a recursion is!**

Comment: @PeterRader Recursion is not circular in general :P

Comment: @PeterRader - the spelling error really changes that to a different problem!

Comment: Seems like someone edited the value of **i** here. It does not return i:1 first in Eclipse, but i:0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What I don't understand here is where the second value of i which is 1 come from.

Regardless of whether or not the method recurses, it *always* returns `i`. So a call of `foo(2)` will always return 2, even though it recurses while printing.

The output message here is confusing because it's not printing `i`. It may help you to understand if you change it to:

```
public int foo(int i) { 
    if (i > 0) { 
        int recurse = foo(i - 1);
        System.out.println("i: " + i + "; foo(i - 1): " + recurse);
    } 
    return i; 
}
```

Note that you'll get the result in "reverse" order because it'll print the result of calling `foo(1)` while still *within* `foo(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to note that the recursive call to `foo()` precedes the print.

Here is the execution:

```
//foo(2)
| calls foo(2-1)
|    //foo(1)
|    | calls foo(1-1)
|    |    //foo(0)
|    |    | prints nothing // because it does not enter the if
|    |    | returns 0      // because 0 is the argument of foo(0)
|    | prints "i: 0" // because 0 is the result of foo(0), called from foo(1)
|    | returns 1     // because 1 is the argument of foo(1)
| prints "i: 1" // because 1 is the result of foo(1), called from foo(2)
| returns 2     // because 2 is the argument of foo(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int foo(int i) { 
  if(i > 0) System.out.println("i: " + foo(i - 1));
  return i; 
}
```

When `i < 1`, the loop is terminated and `i` is returned. However when `i = 2`, the code calls like this in the heap:

```
foo(2) { 
  System.out.println("i: " + foo(1){
    System.out.println("i: " + foo(0){
      // Condition for "if" failed here and does not continue.
      return 0; // Prints: i: 0
    });
    return 1;   // Prints: i: 1
  });
  return 2;     // Returns 2 as foo(2).
}
```

Interior recursive returns are used to print, but only 2 is returned at the end.

Comment: Hi, why would `return 0` print `i:0`(at 5th line)? I think that it simply should return 0 instead of printing `i:0` which comes from print statement under if test. When `i = 0` which does not pass the if test, I think the print statement(sys out) should never be called.

Comment: When `i = 1`, it passed the `if(i > 0)` test in `foo(1)`. As a result `foo(i-1)` was executed and returned `0`. that was printed, while `(i=0) > 0` is false, and hence `i: -1` was not printed. Hope this solves it! :)

Comment: Add: `return 0;` was return statement for `foo(i-1)` in `foo(1)`. `i: 0` was printed because in `foo(1)`, `i > 0` is true.